# Unicode conversion in C++ using Microsoft Access database

Tags: c++, ms-access, unicode

I am given an MS Access database with values in different languages (English,Spanish, German, Chinese). All the characters are displayed properly on the Frontend application except Chinese. It shows all the random values like boxes etc.

So, I looked at the Microsoft access database and it doesn't have any values in Chinese language. All it has is gibberish set of characters, whereas other languages have proper values.
I cannot just update the database with new values in Unicode as the system is very old, and we do not want to change it as it would be a big change.

For example:

```
English text: Printing Receipt ...
Chinese text: ÕýÔÚ´òÓ¡ÊÕ¾Ý¡­ (Yep, I have this value in MS Database)
```

My question is, how can I interpret it? What do I need to do to convert it to Unicode in C++?

Help or suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have someone on hand who can read Chinese and confirm that the results make sense, because this will take trial and error.

It's likely that a `WCHAR[]` array was reinterpreted as a `char[]` in an *unknown* encoding, and then stored as such. To get the Chinese back, your best chance is to reverse the process. I'd start with CP1252 as that is the usual charset for Western Europe.

Still, if any UTF-16 character in the input ended with `00`, then the `char[]` array will be terminated early and part of the string will never have been stored.

Comment: Well, my best help would be from google translate. So far I have been doing the same thing, like reading back the hex values (all possible combinations in all possible encodings), then if possible changing them to Unicode etc by hand on paper, but the unicode counterparts when inserted in google translate give me some funny translated words. So, I thought maybe I was going in wrong direction.

Comment: For example: the word Weekly is stored as ÖÜÆ±. When I read it with ANSI encoding, I get "0xd6dcc6b1", with UTF-8 without BOM "0xc396 0xc39c 0xc386 0xc2b1". Converting between these ANSI and UTF-8 is fine, but that's not an actual word as the ranges of Unicode are not defined for C series.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan: Missing the point there. You'd have to _reinterpret_ the original data, and reinterpret it as UTF-16. What's the Unicode symbol for "Weekly"?

Comment: The Unicode symbol for "Weekly" is "週報", which is U+9031 U+5831.

Comment: That's really problematic because `31` is just the digit `'1'`, so ASCII. That should have been left untouched in any scenario I can imagine.

Comment: Well time to check the database then from where the sheet is filled :) Thanks a lot :)

Comment: It might be GB18030. That's an odd one, but technically still a Unicode encoding.

Comment: Well then the question would be "Which encoding does google translate use?" because I translated "Weekly" to Chinese (traditional). Wiki says "Chinese National Standard GB 18030-2005: ". Maybe my test vector is not right. I will take some test vectors from Unicode charts.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan: That doesn't matter. Web technology is encoding-savvy; it either uses UTF-8 or specifies the actual encoding used. But are you sure that you want Chinese(traditional) ? That's used in Taiwan, and there you expect Big5 instead of GB18030

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84787/discussion-between-muhammad-hassan-and-msalters).